# Use same key for multiple computers

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I have multiple computers that are exclusively available to me.
I am the only account on these computers and they share the same Microsoft account.

I have been getting into github lately and I commit my changes over the Git-Bash command line.

I have two SSH RSA 4096 keys associated with my account on GitHub.
When I commit with the one key it works fine, but my other key is glitchy and does have all the permissions it should have but the commits I make aren't showing up on my account. They show up as my Microsoft account its name in GitHub and when I click contributors I see that the key is allowed to access my private repos and can commit to them. But it is showing up as an unknown GitHub account. I've tried cloning the working key to my other machine to see if that was the problem, but this did not work as the source key is now in this weird state.

What is the problem here and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the commits I make aren't showing up on my account

That has nothing to do with ssh key used to authenticate against GitHub: that ssh key help GitHub validate the authorization (ie, the right to push).

The commits are shown according to the git `user.name` and `user.email` used when they were created (`git commit`)

So check the author name and email of your commits on both instances (in the repo where the commits pushed are displayed with the right account and in the repo where the commits pushed show another account), using [`git log` pretty formatting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %ae"
```